# Startdate to Enddate list of dates Sql query convert into wpf

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net

Someone please help me to convert sql to wpf below is the code.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATE, @EndDate DATE
SELECT @StartDate = '2021-11-01', @EndDate = '2021-12-01'; 
WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
(    SELECT @StartDate AS DATE
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
    FROM ListDates 
    WHERE AllDates < @EndDate)
SELECT AllDates
FROM ListDates
GO
```

**I tried:** Didn't work for me

```vb
Private Sub bb_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim StartDate As Date = "2021-11-01"
    Dim EndDate As Date = "2021-12-01"
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("
    SELECT @StartDate = '2021-11-01', @EndDate = '2021-12-01'; 
    WITH ListDates(AllDates) AS
    (    SELECT @StartDate AS DATE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,AllDates)
        FROM ListDates 
        WHERE AllDates < @EndDate)
    SELECT AllDates
    FROM ListDates
    GO", connection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = StartDate
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = EndDate
    connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

Please someone have a look once and give me any example on this... Thanks...

```vb
Private Sub dg_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim user_id As Integer
    Dim from_date As Date
    Dim to_date As Date
    ' Dim date1 As Date
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("
insert into sqltable4
values
(1, '02/20/2019', '02/23/2019'),
(2, '02/22/2019', '02/28/2019'),
(3, '03/01/2019', '03/05/2019');
with
rows as
(
    select top 1000
    n = 1
    from sys.messages
),
tally as
(
    select n = row_number() over(order by (select null)) - 1
    from rows
),
calendar as
(
    select
    date = dateadd(dd, n, (select min(from_date) from sqltable4))
    from tally
)
select
s.user_id,
c.date
from sqltable4 s
cross join calendar c
where c.date between s.from_date and s.to_date;", connection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = user_id
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@from_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = from_date
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@to_date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = to_date
    connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

below is the screent shot which I'm getting result

[image]

I'm looking for below screenshot result..

[image]

This is the link I found for this... [How to Auto generate dates between date range using SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55108555/how-to-auto-generate-dates-between-date-range-using-sql-query)

Comment: Tell us what "Didn't work for me" means.  What errors did you get?  What data/response did you get and how was it different from what you expected?

Comment: Can you please explain more clearly what you are trying to do? ExecuteNonQuery won't return any data. GO should not be included. What does this have to do with WPF? Why are you overriding the dates passed in as parameters?

Comment: Why are you declaring variables in the query when you really want parameters? The query you need to execute is just the `SELECT` clause

Comment: @RBarryYoung, I'm not getting any error message its executing but Sql table not showing anything....

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I looking to create dates list in sql table I don't know how to do it give me any example on this if it is possibul...

Answer (score 0):

It's likely the query runs correctly and then finishes with no visible changes.

This is a `SELECT` query, so it won't change or add anything in the database; it only returns results. But the VB code uses `ExecuteNonQuery()` to run the query, which doesn't retrieve any results from the queries it runs.

Instead, you need to use `ExecuteReader()` or use `SqlDataAdapter.Fill()` to put the results in a `DataTable`, or change the SQL to `INSERT` the results in a table.

Comment: How can I use insert command in sql. Could you provide any example

Comment: @HemaLatha Sounds like you may be trying to run before you can walk.

Comment: I modified the code with adding insert. Could you check it once. Its showing only Insert values not generating List of dates... Thanks...